# Getting XML node based on text value, that ends with XML

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have this xml document, where I want to read documenturl where innertext ends with .xml

```
<Root>
  <hits>
    <total>4</total>
    <max_score />
    <hits>
      <_index>offentliggoerelser-prod-20161006</_index>
      <_type>offentliggoerelse</_type>
      <_id>urn:ofk:oid:23640715</_id>
      <_score />
      <_source>
        <dokumenter>
          <dokumentUrl>url.pdf</dokumentUrl>
          <dokumentMimeType>application/pdf</dokumentMimeType>
          <dokumentType>KONCERNREGNSKAB_FOR_OVERLIGGENDE_MODER</dokumentType>
        </dokumenter>
        <dokumenter>
          <dokumentUrl>url.xml</dokumentUrl>
          <dokumentMimeType>application/xml</dokumentMimeType>
          <dokumentType>AARSRAPPORT</dokumentType>
        </dokumenter>
        <dokumenter>
          <dokumentUrl>url.pdf</dokumentUrl>
          <dokumentMimeType>application/pdf</dokumentMimeType>
          <dokumentType>AARSRAPPORT</dokumentType>
        </dokumenter>
      </_source>
      <sort>1490355849989</sort>
    </hits>
  </hits>
</Root>
```

I am trying to read `dokumentUrl` that ends with '.xml' only.
I try to use LINQ

```
XDocument mydoc = XDocument.Load(file);    
XDocument xPlatformXml = new XDocument(mydoc);
XElement xel = xPlatformXml.Element("_source")
                           .Elements("dokumenter")
                           .Where(x => x.Element("dokumentUrl").Value == ".xml")
                           .SingleOrDefault();
```

but it does not work, can anyone pls help me

Answer (score 2):

You can check if you have the `descendants node` that has value ends with `.xml`

```
XDocument mydoc = XDocument.Load(file);
XDocument xPlatformXml = new XDocument(mydoc);
XElement xel = xPlatformXml.Root.Descendants()
                                    .Where(x => x.Name == "dokumentUrl" && x.Value.EndsWith(".xml"))
                                    .SingleOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
XDocument xPlatformXml = new XDocument(mydoc);
XElement xel = xPlatformXml.Element("_source")
                           .Elements("dokumenter")
                           .Where(x => x.Element("dokumentUrl").Value.EndsWith(".xml"))
                           .SingleOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

When using the `Element` method you must specify the entire path from the document root to the desired nodes. For example:

```
var xel = xPlatformXml.Element("Root")
    .Element("hits")
    .Element("hits")
    .Element("_source")
    .Elements("dokumenter")
    .Elements("dokumentUrl")
    .SingleOrDefault(x => x.Value.EndsWith(".xml"));
```

Or you can use the `Descendants` method. It is more concise, but may affect performance.

```
var xel2 = xPlatformXml.Descendants("dokumentUrl")
    .SingleOrDefault(x => x.Value.EndsWith(".xml"));
```